# Getting a tweet id from a tweet link using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, praw

I am creating a bot for Reddit that posts a tweet's text, author, and a couple of other small things on submissions that directly link to the tweet (example - https://twitter.com/John_Yuki_Bot/status/889453450664304641).

However, I can't find anything in the Tweepy documentation that lets me extract a tweet's id from a tweet link so that I can use `api.get_status(status_id)` in order to get the status text, status author, and so on.

How can I get the status id just using links like that?

EDIT - The code at the end of the link (889453450664304641) is the status ID. I need to have this in its own variable so that Tweepy can use it.

Comment: Is `889453450664304641` the status ID in the example URL you provide? If so could you not simply extract it yourself from the URL?

Comment: Yes, that is the status ID.

However, the bot gets that link on its own by using PRAW. After it does this, I need to somehow get that status ID in its own variable so that I can use it with Tweepy. As far as I am aware, I can't get the tweet metadata from the tweet URL, I have to get the tweet ID for that.

Comment: But if you have the URL you can extract the ID with a regex or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple

```
url.split('/')[-1]
```

and you get what you want

Comment: Thanks, this did it.

Comment: its will not work https://twitter.com/FarhangNamdar/status/1230554753182003203?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw any suggestion to fetch tweet id

Answer (score 1):

```
url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]
```

the first part (`.split('/')[-1]`) splits the string based on the `/` character and chooses the last element. On top of that, we do `.split('?')[0]`, which splits the result based on `?` character and chooses the first part. This will remove any arguments being passed in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
let twitterLink = 'https://twitter.com/i/status/1565542250158837761';
      let tweetId = "";
            let arr = twitterLink.split("/");
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              let el = arr[i];
              if (el === "status") {
                tweetId = arr[i + 1];
              }
            }
```

Therefore you get the element of array that comes after status and for twetter that is always ID